# wordpress , problems with text blocks, they dissapear

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, textblock, dokan

I'm a beginner in wordpress,recently  I installed the dokan  plugin for my online shop, gave me problems and I read that the solution was add this code

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mgt_dequeue_stylesandscripts',99);

function mgt_dequeue_stylesandscripts() {
if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) ) {
wp_dequeue_style( 'select2' );
wp_deregister_style( 'select2' );

wp_dequeue_script( 'select2');
wp_deregister_script('select2');

 } }
```

I am using the handy store template, so I put the code in the file "function", when I use this function, the text-blocks stop working, literally they disappear, and when I remove the code they come back again, how could I solve it?

the above problem was that I had errors when uploading banners and photos.

the code of the function is this

```
<?php
    /* PlumTree functions and definitions */

    /** Contents:
            - Additional image sizes.
            - Google Fonts for your site.
            - Handy Setup.
            - Enqueue scripts and styles.
            - Handy Init Sidebars.
            - Options Panel.
            - Adding features.
            - Backend notifications on theme activation.
    **/

    /* Set up the content width value based on the theme's design. */
    if (!isset( $content_width )) $content_width = 1200;


    /* Adding additional image sizes. */
    if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
        add_image_size( 'product-extra-gallery-thumb', 70, 70, true );
        add_image_size( 'pt-cat-thumb', 25, 25, true );
        add_image_size( 'carousel-medium', 500, 500, true);
        add_image_size( 'carousel-large', 760, 500, true);
        add_image_size( 'pt-product-thumbs', 123, 123, true);
        add_image_size( 'pt-recent-posts-thumb', 263, 174, true);
        add_image_size( 'pt-sidebar-thumbs', 80, 80, true);
        add_image_size( 'pt-vendor-product-thumbs', 120, 120, true);
    }


    /* Setting Google Fonts for your site */
    if ( ! class_exists( 'handyFonts' ) ) {
        class handyFonts {
            static function get_default_fonts() {
                $handy_default_fonts = array('Open Sans', 'Roboto', 'Lato');
                return $handy_default_fonts;
            }
        }
    }


    /* Handy Setup. Set up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress features. */
    if ( ! function_exists( 'plumtree_setup' ) ) {
        function plumtree_setup() {

            // Translation availability
            load_theme_textdomain( 'plumtree', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

            // Add RSS feed links to <head> for posts and comments.
            add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

            add_theme_support( "title-tag" );

            add_theme_support( "custom-header");

            // Enable support for Post Thumbnails.
            add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

            set_post_thumbnail_size( 1138, 450, true );

            // Nav menus.
            register_nav_menus( array(
                'header-top-nav'   => __( 'Top Menu', 'plumtree' ),
                'primary-nav'      => __( 'Primary Menu (Under Logo)', 'plumtree' ),
            ) );

            // Switch default core markup for search form, comment form, and comments to output valid HTML5.
            add_theme_support( 'html5', array(
                'search-form', 'comment-form', 'comment-list', 'gallery', 'caption'
            ) );

            // Enable support for Post Formats.
            add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array(
                'aside', 'image', 'video', 'audio', 'quote', 'link', 'gallery',
            ) );

            // This theme allows users to set a custom background.
            add_theme_support( 'custom-background', array(
                'default-color' => 'FFFFFF',
            ) );

            // Enable woocommerce support
            add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );

            // Enable layouts support
            $pt_layouts = array(
                    array('value' => 'one-col', 'label' => esc_html__('1 Column (no sidebars)', 'plumtree'), 'icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/theme-options/images/one-col.png'),
                    array('value' => 'two-col-left', 'label' => esc_html__('2 Columns, sidebar on left', 'plumtree'), 'icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/theme-options/images/two-col-left.png'),
                    array('value' => 'two-col-right', 'label' => esc_html__('2 Columns, sidebar on right', 'plumtree'), 'icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/theme-options/images/two-col-right.png'),
            );
            add_theme_support( 'plumtree-layouts', apply_filters('pt_default_layouts', $pt_layouts) );

        }
    }
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'plumtree_setup' );


    /* Enqueue scripts and styles for the front end. */
    function plumtree_scripts() {
        /* Get vendor store */
        $vendor_shop = '';
        if ( class_exists('WCV_Vendors') ) {
            $vendor_shop = urldecode( get_query_var( 'vendor_shop' ) );
        }

        //---- CSS Styles
        wp_enqueue_style( 'pt-basic', get_stylesheet_uri() );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'pt-grid-and-effects', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/grid-and-effects.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'pt-icon-fonts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/icon-fonts.min.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'pt-additional-styles', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/additional-styles.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'pt-vc-styles', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/visual-composer-styles.css' );
        if ( class_exists('Woocommerce') && class_exists('WCV_Vendors') ) {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'pt-vendors-styles', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/vendor-styles.css' );
        }

        //---- JS libraries
        wp_enqueue_script( 'hoverIntent', array('jquery') );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'lazy-sizes', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lazysizes.js', array(), '1.5.0', false );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'easings', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/easing.1.3.js', array('jquery'), '1.3', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'images-loaded', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/imagesloaded.js', array('jquery'), '4.1.0', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'countdown', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/countdown.js', array('jquery'), '2.0.2', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.5', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'owl-carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/owl.carousel.js', array('jquery'), '1.3.3', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'magnific-popup', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/magnific-popup.js', array('jquery'), '1.1.0', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'select2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/select2.js', array('jquery'), '3.5.2', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'ion-checkradio', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ion.checkRadio.js', array('jquery'), '2.0', true );
        if ( is_archive() || is_home() ||
             is_tax() ||
             ( $vendor_shop && $vendor_shop!='' ) ||
             is_page_template( 'page-templates/gallery-page.php' ) ||
             is_page_template( 'page-templates/portfolio-page.php' ) ) {
                 wp_enqueue_script( 'isotope', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/isotope.js', array('jquery'), '2.2.0', true );
        }
        wp_enqueue_script( 'pt-basic-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/helper.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

        //---- Comments script-----------
        if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
        }
    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mgt_dequeue_stylesandscripts',99);

    function mgt_dequeue_stylesandscripts() {
    if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) ) {
        wp_dequeue_style( 'select2' );
        wp_deregister_style( 'select2' );

        wp_dequeue_script( 'select2');
        wp_deregister_script('select2');

    } }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'plumtree_scripts' );


    /* Handy Init Sidebars. */
    if (!function_exists('plumtree_widgets_init')){
        function plumtree_widgets_init() {
            // Default Sidebars
            register_sidebar( array(
                'name' => __( 'Blog Sidebar', 'plumtree' ),
                'id' => 'sidebar-blog',
                'description' => __( 'Appears on single blog posts and on Blog Page', 'plumtree' ),
                'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
                'after_widget' => '</aside>',
                'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title" itemprop="name">',
                'after_title' => '</h3>',
            ) );
            if ( handy_get_option('header_top_panel') == 'on' ) {
                register_sidebar( array(
                    'name' => __( 'Header Top Panel Sidebar', 'plumtree' ),
                    'id' => 'top-sidebar',
                    'description' => __( 'Located at the top of site', 'plumtree' ),
                    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="%2$s right-aligned">',
                    'after_widget' => '</aside>',
                    'before_title' => '<!--',
                    'after_title' => '-->',
                ) );
            }
            register_sidebar( array(
                'name' => __( 'Header (Logo group) sidebar', 'plumtree' ),
                'id' => 'hgroup-sidebar',
                'description' => __( 'Located to the right from header', 'plumtree' ),
                'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
                'after_widget' => '</aside>',
                'before_title' => '',
                'after_title' => '',
            ) );
            register_sidebar( array(
                'name' => __( 'Front Page Sidebar', 'plumtree' ),
                'id' => 'sidebar-front',
                'description' => __( 'Appears when using the optional Front Page template with a page set as Static Front Page', 'plumtree' ),
                'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
                'after_widget' => '</aside>',
                'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title itemprop="name">',
                'after_title' => '</h3>',
            ) );
            register_sidebar( array(
                'name' => __( 'Pages Sidebar', 'plumtree' ),
                'id' => 'sidebar-pages',
                'description' => __( 'Appears on Pages', 'plumtree' ),
                'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
                'after_widget' => '</aside>',
                'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title itemprop="name">',
                'after_title' => '</h3>',
            ) );
            if ( class_exists('Woocommerce') ) {
                register_sidebar( array(
                    'name' => __( 'Shop Page Sidebar', 'plumtree' ),
                    'id' => 'sidebar-shop',
                    'description' => __( 'Appears on Products page', 'plumtree' ),
                    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
                    'after_widget' => '</aside>',
                    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title itemprop="name">',
                    'after_title' => '</h3>',
                ) );
                register_sidebar( array(
                    'name' => __( 'Single Product Page Sidebar', 'plumtree' ),
                    'id' => 'sidebar-product',
                    'description' => __( 'Appears on Single Products page', 'plumtree' ),
                    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
                    'after_widget' => '</aside>',
                    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title itemprop="name">',
                    'after_title' => '</h3>',
                ) );
                if ( class_exists('WCV_Vendors') ) {
                    register_sidebar( array(
                        'name' => __( 'Vendor Shop Page Sidebar', 'plumtree' ),
                        'id' => 'sidebar-vendor',
                        'description' => __( 'Appears on Vendors Shop Page', 'plumtree' ),
                        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
                        'after_widget' => '</aside>',
                        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title itemprop="name">',
                        'after_title' => '</h3>',
                    ) );
                }
            }
          // Footer Sidebars
          register_sidebar( array(
            'name' => __( 'Footer Sidebar Col#1', 'plumtree' ),
            'id' => 'footer-sidebar-1',
            'description' => __( 'Located in the footer of the site', 'plumtree' ),
            'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget' => '</aside>',
            'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title itemprop="name">',
            'after_title' => '</h3>',
            ) );
          register_sidebar( array(
            'name' => __( 'Footer Sidebar Col#2', 'plumtree' ),
            'id' => 'footer-sidebar-2',
            'description' => __( 'Located in the footer of the site', 'plumtree' ),
            'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget' => '</aside>',
            'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title itemprop="name">',
            'after_title' => '</h3>',
          ) );
          register_sidebar( array(
            'name' => __( 'Footer Sidebar Col#3', 'plumtree' ),
            'id' => 'footer-sidebar-3',
            'description' => __( 'Located in the footer of the site', 'plumtree' ),
            'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget' => '</aside>',
            'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title itemprop="name">',
            'after_title' => '</h3>',
          ) );
          register_sidebar( array(
            'name' => __( 'Footer Sidebar Col#4', 'plumtree' ),
            'id' => 'footer-sidebar-4',
            'description' => __( 'Located in the footer of the site', 'plumtree' ),
            'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget' => '</aside>',
            'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title itemprop="name">',
            'after_title' => '</h3>',
          ) );
          // Custom Sidebars
          register_sidebar( array(
            'name' => __( 'Top Footer Sidebar', 'plumtree' ),
            'id' => 'top-footer-sidebar',
            'description' => __( 'Located in the footer of the site', 'plumtree' ),
            'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget' => '</aside>',
            'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title itemprop="name">',
            'after_title' => '</h3>',
          ) );
          if ( handy_get_option('filters_sidebar')=='on' ) {
                register_sidebar( array(
                    'name' => __( 'Special Filters Sidebar', 'plumtree' ),
                  'id' => 'filters-sidebar',
                  'description' => __( 'Located at the top of the products page', 'plumtree' ),
                  'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
                  'after_widget' => '</aside>',
                  'before_title' => '<h3 class="dropdown-filters-title">',
                  'after_title' => '</h3>',
                ) );
            }
            if ( handy_get_option('front_page_special_sidebar')=='on' ) {
                register_sidebar( array(
                    'name' => __( 'Special Front Page Sidebar', 'plumtree' ),
                  'id' => 'front-special-sidebar',
                  'description' => __( 'Located at the bottom of the page (appears only when using Front Page Template)', 'plumtree' ),
                  'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 lazyload" data-expand="-100" >',
                  'after_widget' => '</aside>',
                  'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title" itemprop="name">',
                  'after_title' => '</h3>',
                ) );
            }
        }
        add_action( 'widgets_init', 'plumtree_widgets_init' );
    }


    /* Options Panel */
    define( 'OPTIONS_FRAMEWORK_DIRECTORY', get_template_directory_uri() . '/theme-options/' );
    require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/theme-options/options-framework.php' );

    // Loads options.php from child or parent theme
    $optionsfile = locate_template( 'options.php' );
    load_template( $optionsfile );

    function handy_prefix_options_menu_filter( $menu ) {
        $menu['mode'] = 'menu';
        $menu['page_title'] = esc_html__( 'Handy Theme Options', 'plumtree');
        $menu['menu_title'] = esc_html__( 'Handy Theme Options', 'plumtree');
        $menu['menu_slug'] = 'handy-theme-options';
        return $menu;
    }
    add_filter( 'optionsframework_menu', 'handy_prefix_options_menu_filter' );


    /* Adding features */
    // Widgets
    require_once( get_template_directory() . '/widgets/class-pt-widget-contacts.php');
    require_once( get_template_directory() . '/widgets/class-pt-widget-socials.php');
    require_once( get_template_directory() . '/widgets/class-pt-widget-search.php');
    require_once( get_template_directory() . '/widgets/class-pt-widget-login.php');
    require_once( get_template_directory() . '/widgets/class-pt-widget-most-viewed-posts.php');
    require_once( get_template_directory() . '/widgets/class-pt-widget-recent-posts.php');
    require_once( get_template_directory() . '/widgets/class-pt-widget-comments-with-avatars.php');
    require_once( get_template_directory() . '/widgets/pay-icons/class-pt-widget-pay-icons.php');
    if ( class_exists('Woocommerce') ) {
        require_once( get_template_directory() . '/widgets/class-pt-widget-cart.php');
        require_once( get_template_directory() . '/widgets/class-pt-widget-categories.php');
    }
    if ( handy_get_option('site_post_likes')=='on' ) {
        require_once( get_template_directory() . '/widgets/class-pt-widget-user-likes.php');
        require_once( get_template_directory() . '/widgets/class-pt-widget-popular-posts.php');
    }
    if ( class_exists('Woocommerce') && class_exists('WCV_Vendors') ) {
        require_once( get_template_directory() . '/widgets/class-pt-widget-vendors-products.php');
    }

    // Required functions
    require_once( get_template_directory() . '/inc/pt-google-fonts.php');
    require_once( get_template_directory() . '/inc/pt-theme-layouts.php');
    require_once( get_template_directory() . '/inc/pt-functions.php');
    require_once( get_template_directory() . '/inc/pt-login-register.php');
    require_once( get_template_directory() . '/inc/pt-tgm-plugin-activation.php');
    require_once( get_template_directory() . '/inc/pt-self-install.php');
    if ( handy_get_option('blog_share_buttons')=='on' ||
         handy_get_option('use_pt_shares_for_product')=='on' ) {
        require_once( get_template_directory() . '/inc/pt-share-buttons.php');
    }
    if ( handy_get_option('site_post_likes')=='on' ) {
        require_once( get_template_directory() . '/inc/pt-post-like.php');
    }
    if ( class_exists('Woocommerce') ) {
        require_once( get_template_directory() . '/inc/pt-woo-modification.php');
    }
    if ( class_exists('WCV_Vendors') ) {
        require_once( get_template_directory() . '/inc/pt-vendors-modification.php');
        if ( handy_get_option('show_wcv_favourite_vendors')=='on' ) {
            require_once( get_template_directory() . '/inc/pt-favourite-vendors.php');
        }
    }
    if ( handy_get_option('blog_pagination')=='infinite' ) {
        require_once( get_template_directory() . '/inc/pt-infinite-blog.php');
    }
    if ( handy_get_option('site_custom_colors') == 'on') {
        require_once( get_template_directory() . '/inc/pt-color-sheme.php');
    }

    // Adding pagebuilders custom shortcodes
    if (class_exists('IG_Pb_Init')) {
      require_once( get_template_directory() . '/shortcodes/add_to_contentbuilder.php' );
    }
    if ( class_exists( 'WPBakeryShortCode' ) ) {
        require_once( get_template_directory() . '/shortcodes/composer_shortcodes/banner.php');
        require_once( get_template_directory() . '/shortcodes/composer_shortcodes/contact-member.php');
        require_once( get_template_directory() . '/shortcodes/composer_shortcodes/recent-post.php');
        require_once( get_template_directory() . '/shortcodes/composer_shortcodes/carousel.php');
        require_once( get_template_directory() . '/shortcodes/composer_shortcodes/sale-carousel.php');
        require_once( get_template_directory() . '/shortcodes/composer_shortcodes/testimonials.php');
        require_once( get_template_directory() . '/shortcodes/composer_shortcodes/woo-codes.php');
        require_once( get_template_directory() . '/shortcodes/composer_shortcodes/vendors-carousel.php');
        require_once( get_template_directory() . '/shortcodes/composer_shortcodes/promo-text.php');
    }

    // Add do_shortcode filter.
    add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');

    // Live preview with RTL
    if( isset( $_GET['rtl_demo'] ) && $_GET['rtl_demo']=='true' ){
        function add_rtl_css() {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'plumtree-rtl', get_template_directory_uri().'/rtl.css' );
        }
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_rtl_css' );
    }

    /* Backend notifications on theme activation */
    //add_action('after_switch_theme', 'pt_add_alerts');
    function pt_add_alerts () {
        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'pt_add_alert_text' );
    }

    function pt_add_alert_text() {
       echo ' <div class="notice error is-dismissible">
                <p><strong style="color: #DC3232;">Warning!</strong> It is strongly recommended to read our instructions before installing sample data, it may destroy your existing data!</p>
                            <p>We also offer <strong>paid sample data installation</strong>. Please contact support on this matter!</p>
                            <p><strong><a href="http://handystorehelp.themes.zone/#installing-sample-data" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Read Instructions</a></strong>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                            <strong><a href="http://support.themes.zone/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Contact Support</a></strong></p>
              </div>';
    }

    /* Registers an editor stylesheet for the theme. */
    function handy_theme_add_editor_styles() {
        add_editor_style( 'custom-editor-style.css' );
    }
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'handy_theme_add_editor_styles' );
```

Comment: Did you check some error with your browser dev tools for the upload, before trying removing the script ?

Comment: And you talk about dokkan but isaw some code related to wcvendor ?

Comment: With your function you dequeue the template select2, you need to adjust the priority or change the position of the code (before plumtree_scripts)

Comment: yes, the template originally came to the mcvendors, I just add the code that was in the support forums

Comment: You need to work with a child theme, it's look like you are working on the parent theme functions.php.

Comment: @Benoti ok I try with the priorities, but the function is well ?, I should change something?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that

Comment: but I read that if I work with child themes functions are inherited, not be the same?

Comment: I don't know which select2 you need to dequeue : woocommerce one or theme ? Have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547598/how-to-unload-select2-script-styles-loaded-by-new-woocommerce-2-3-x, and tell more about your upload errors (with another questions)

Comment: hi @Benoti ,  I managed to focus a little mistake, I posted new code in this topic
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467675/select2-is-not-a-function-wordpress

Comment: @FelipeCastillo the problem described in the link in your last comment comes up because you "uninstall' the select2 plugin that is needed in your theme. You can see it queued in `functions.php` on the line 126. Judging from that, your theme is likely to need the *select2* jQuery plugin. I reckon, you need to find a solution to your original problem that is not based on removing select2.

Comment: Also as @Benoti suggests, you ought to work on a child theme. It's just a good practice that will prevent you a lot of headache when there's an upgrade for your theme. And it makes it easier to see your own added code. Here's a child theme starter pack I use – https://bitbucket.org/snippets/crs1138/a4zGn/wp-child-theme-starter-kit